# Why is applying a model to a batch of data in Spark via mapPartitions() much faster than applying to individual rows via map()?

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark

I'm trying to learn Spark and especially it's functionality `mapPartitions()`.
Let's say we have a dataset of 1000 datapoints.

If you apply batch processing by chunking the data into 10 partitions then each partition will have 100 datapoints.

If we apply model to each partition (batch processing) then we will apply on the first 100 rows, then proceed to the next partition and we will apply the model on each of the 100 rows of the second partition and so on.

If we apply the model to each row to the whole dataset of 1000 datapoints, why is it so different than applying the same model in batches?

What seems paradoxical to me is that either way you are going through the entire dataset because you are generating predictions for each row either way!

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your model is an API endpoint or some remote server connection. With map you'll to establish a connection every single time where as with mapPartitiions a connection will be established only once per partition. Another thing to clear is that using either map or map partitions data within the partitions will be processed in parallel and not one partition after another.